# Flutter does not compile after adding flutter_email_sender plugin

Tags: android, plugins, flutter

I am trying to redirect my users to an email client so they can send an attachement i have created within my app.
However on adding flutter_email_sender to my pubspec.yaml my app no longer compiles.

I am getting the following error:
[image: Error]

I have tried adding the line to my AndroidManifest with no success.

"The prefix 'tools' for at tribute 'tools:replace' associated with an element type 'application'  is not bound"

The documentation says i should have compileSdkVersion 28 which i have.

How do i resolve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You need to migrate to `androidx`. Which means you need to update all packages that you added in your `pubspec.yaml` to ensure that they are compatible with `androidx`. So make sure that all your packages are up to date, then open the android project of your flutter app with android studio. Go to `Refactor`-> `Migrate to AndroidX`. Then rebuild your project. And you will be fine.
Hope it helps!